# Can Spell Check of Electronics Terms be Updated?

Tags: bug

The spell checker doesn't seem to know many common electronic terms.  This is quite surprising for an electronics forum.  Is there a library file somewhere that can be updated with common electronics terms such as inductor, MOSFET, ferrite, and I'm sure many others?

Comment: This question is asked at least twice a year, I asked the same question years ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAICT, spell-checking is entirely a function of your browser and its underlying OS, and has nothing to do with StackExchange *per se*.

In other words, if you want to change its behavior, you need to investigate how to change the settings in your browser and/or operating system.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess that makes sense.  I suppose I can now blame Google Chrome for not knowing what an inductor is :-).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't [blame google chrome](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6503/can-spell-check-of-electronics-terms-be-updated#comment15599_6504), at least not directly. You'll have to look further and/or deeper into language settings and spelling dictionaries, possibly even saved mipsellings of words. Oh no!

> [image]